# Send Requests to MySQL or MariaDB with Python 3

Tags: python, mysql, mariadb

I want to send requests to MySQL Database in Python 3 any way to do that?

I have found a similar question with Python 2 though non with 3.*)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first install mysql-connector using python package manage i.e.(pip)

they try following code

```
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user="yourusername",
    passwd="yourpassword"
 )

print(mydb)
```